# UIBarButtonItem never returns YES in accessibilityElementIsFocused when selected

Tags: objective-c, accessibility, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to get my apps accessibility improved with VoiceOver. I'm just left now with wanting to know when a button on my lower bar is selected for voice over however

```
[barbutton accessibilityElementIsFocused]
```

never returns true.

I've even subclassed uibarbutton and tried using

```
accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused
accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus
```

These aren't firing either!

I've set isAccessibilityElement as a true boolean in the item's user defined runtime attributes.. sort of run out of options.

The button is being selected its just never telling me that it is. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've set up a a test project and have exactly the same behavior. I can't get the focus true on an `UIBarButtonItem` subclass. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report 21276502

Comment: Thanks for the update and effort. Will have to leave out support for reading out the bar button over time until it's fixed. Cheers!

Comment: Any update on this ? facing same issue need that event to handle something.

Comment: Any update? Still seeing the same bug on iOS 11.2.1.